# What type of function is this?

Tags: functions

I was attempting to factor the following expression when I realized I didn't even know what type of function the expression is. Does anyone know? $x^4-9x^x+12x-4$.

Comment: Ugly. I'm going with ugly. That, or typo.

Comment: May I ask from which course this question is?

Comment: It's from Precalc, but my teacher likes to give these kinds of  convoluted questions each week as an extra challenge for students who are interested. I mostly do them out of interest.

Comment: I'm been puzzling over it for the whole weekend here is what I've come up with so far. As far as I know the x^x is basically Knuth's up arrow notation as in x^2=x↑↑2, which is the same notation used to express Graham's number. If the equation was just 9x^x-4 then you could factor it as (3\sqrt(x)^x-2)(3\qrt(x)+2), but sadly that is not the answer. I don't know if that helps, but that's all I got so far.

Comment: Not all functions are named, or belong to a named class.

Comment: Are there anyways to factor this function then? Since it's neither polynomial nor exponential, which way do you factor it?

Comment: If your instructor provides an answer, please post it here (you can answer your own question). I'd love to see it. It's exasperating, since I've come up with solutions that *almost* work. In particular, one can use the fact that $x^x-x^2$ and $x^{x/2}-x$ both have roots $x=1, 2$, so could be factors.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a typo and should actually be $x^4-9x^2+12x-4$, that has a particularly nice factorization:
$$\begin{align}
x^4-9x^2+12x-4&=(x-1)(x^3+x^2-8x+4)&\quad\text{since $x=1$ is a root}\\
&=(x-1)(x-2)(x^2+3x-2)&\quad\text{since $x=2$ is a root}\\
&=(x^2-3x+2)(x^2+3x-2)
\end{align}$$
or, if you prefer, 
$$
x^4-9x^2+12x-4=x^4-(3x-2)^2
$$
In a precalc course, it's unlikely that you'd see anything like $x^x$ as part of an equation you'd have to solve, so the default would be to assume a typo (or thinko, which I do more often than I'd like).

**Update**. It's worth mentioning that $x=1, x=2$ are also roots of
$$
x^4-9x^x+12x-4
$$

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I do not believe it is a typo. The question is suppose to be challenging. However, I am also equally unsure if there is a factorization. At this point I'm leaning towards there is no possible factorization, but it would be nice to see some definitive proof just out of curiosity.

Comment: I have looked into factorization of a polynomial over a finite field, but I haven't come up with a conclusive answer yet. I'll continue trying for maybe a few more hours then I'll probably call it a day and try again some other time.

Comment: @user97722 if its not a typo, then the given function is definitely not a polynomial.